# Google Apps Script object confusion

Tags: object, google-apps-script

This top code inserts `adsf` into the spreadsheet instead of `something else`, however the code below logs `something else` as expected... what's going on here?  Set the Apps Script function to myFunction...  (P.S. I deleted and updated my previous question with this question)

This code doesn't work as expected:

```
var obj = {variable:"adsf"};

function myFunction() {
  function scheduledScript(plusMonth,plusDay,plusHour,plusMinute) {
    obj.variable = "something else";
    var now = new Date();
    var year = now.getFullYear();
    var MONTH = now.getMonth();
    var DAY = now.getDate();
    var HOUR = now.getHours();
    var MINUTE = now.getMinutes();
    var seconds = now.getSeconds();
    var milliseconds = now.getMilliseconds();
    var date = new Date(year,MONTH+plusMonth,DAY+plusDay,HOUR+plusHour,MINUTE+plusMinute,10,0);
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('send').timeBased().at(date).create();
  }
  scheduledScript(0,0,0,1);
}

function send() {
  Logger.log(obj.variable); //"adsf"      
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1z28v6Y_4kwTxfqXLvEb1Zo81QJGZ8AfxkoSFYP5LM8E").setActiveSelection("H1").setValue(obj.variable);
}
```

This code works as expected:

```
var obj = {variable:"asdf"};

function myFunction() {
  function process() {
    Logger.log(obj.variable); //"asdf"
    obj.variable = "something else";
    notify();
  }
  process();
}

function notify () {
  Logger.log(obj.variable); //"something else"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No confusion there.

Your first script sample sets a time-based trigger which executes `send()` function. When it executes, it gets the `obj` global variable value you set in the first line of your code. The trigger does not run your `myFunction()` function which changes the `obj` global variable value. Hence you see `adsf` entered in the spreadsheet cell.

Comment: I'm confused... the trigger is only called because myFunction has it being called on the last line... that would mean everything would be updated before the trigger executes

Comment: Triggers run in their own session space, separate from any user session. Your `myFunction()` function sets the new value of `obj` variable and then creates a trigger. But when the trigger executes, it is a separate session, a new execution of your script, so it gets the original `obj` variable value.